# On-Topic, Off-Topic

Tags: discussion

I read with interest Jay Jennings comments on:

[Sound Design/Sound Engineering Masters in Europe](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/45933/sound-design-sound-engineering-masters-in-europe/45940#45940)

...and wonder whether it is worth opening discussion on what we consider on-topic and off-topic?

I for one, would be happy to answer a question related to educational resources and institutes, but am remarkably quick at voting to close questions that are obviously technical support questions that are specific to one manufacturers product which IMHO are clearly best directed at the manufacturer.

Ah yeah, and of course anything even remotely related to consumer audio.

Are we in a place where this needs any sort of review?

Can we also consider making the on/off topic information a little more prominent for new users?

Further to this, there is very little expressed in https://sound.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic in regard to "audiophile" or "consumer audio" questions which appear prominently where a close vote is suggested. Can we look at ways of making this more obvious to new posters?

Comment: Is there anything we can do to improve the visibility of what is off-topic - seems like every question coming in to the stack at the moment is scraping the barrel in terms of quality or relevance?

Comment: Looking at this a couple of years later, course recommendations seem great compared to the "How do I wire X to Y?" which we seem to be getting a lot of recently. RTFM.